# How to align vertically a Label and textbox in panel heading with bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I need center vertically a label and textbox with bootstrap in a Panel Heading. I have this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    Categorias
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="prueba" runat="server"></i></span>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtFecha" runat="server" placeholder="Seleccione Fecha" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How i can do this.

Comment: Please paste the relevant code in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      Categorias
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="prueba" runat="server"></i>
        </span>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtFecha" runat="server" placeholder="Seleccione Fecha" ></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```